# Symfony2 - Factory method in collection form

Tags: php, symfony

I think this problem should be relatively easy to solve, but I cannot find the answer anywhere. I'm using Symfony 2.3 and I have two mutually dependent classes, let's call them `Parent` and `Child` class respectively.

`Child`'s lifecycle depends on there being a `Parent` existing, so in the constructor I declare:

```
public function __construct(Parent $parent, $foo, $bar)
{
    $this->parent = $parent;
    $this->foo = $foo;
    $this->bar = $baz;
}
```

In such a way, I use the factory method pattern in order to create `Child` given the dependency of both classes. In `Parent` I have this method:

```
public function createChild($foo, $bar)
{
    $c = new Child($this, $foo, $bar);
    $this->addChildren($c); //The children are stored in a Doctrine's ArrayCollection
    return $c;
}
```

Now I'm making the form to create `Parent` and several `Child`. `ParentType` has:

```
class ParentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('baz', 'text') //Merely a property of Parent
                ->add('children', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => 'childrentype',
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'label' => false
                ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'My\Bundle\Parent',
            'empty_data' => function (FormInterface $form) {
                return new \My\Bundle\Parent(
                        $form->get('baz')->getData()
                    );
            }
        ));
    }

    //...
}
```

And `ChildType` has:

```
class ChildType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('foo', 'text', array('label' => false)
                )->add('bar', 'text', array('label' => false));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'My\Bundle\Child',
            'empty_data' => function (FormInterface $form) {
                return $form->getParent()->getData()->createChild(
                        $form->get('foo')->getData(),
                        $form->get('bar')->getData()
                    );
            }
        ));
    }

   //...
}
```

In theory this should work, but I have the following issues:

1. Symfony is forcing me to declare `addChildren` and `removeChildren`. No big deal, I did that.
2. After I do that, I get the following error:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function createChild() on a non-object in (route)\ChildType.php line 22

Is there something I'm doing wrong or that I should considerate in order to not break proper OOP programming and make the form work? Thank you.

Comment: put it through a debugger. You are expecting to get back a class but the error definately says it is something else. You have a couple lines of code here, so I can't see through, but if you set up a couple of breakpoints you can see wht return value you are actually getting.

Comment: I can't do that in PHP. I am expecting an object and I'm not getting one, however I wonder why I'm not getting one. Unless the collection is created before its parent calls to setData?

Comment: then just simply use a var_dump($form->getParent()->getData()).

Comment: I don't think that's neccesary. I'm pretty much assuming I'm getting a `null` value and the message is being explicit that I'm not receiving an object.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with var_dump?

Comment: I instead did `echo gettype($form->getParent()->getData())` and I get `NULL`. Exactly what I thought.

Comment: At that stage you shouldn't have the parent form's data available. *Maybe* if you set it via the `data` property instead of `empty_data`. In any case `FormEvents` should solve such dependent cases.

Comment: I was trying to do something using `FormEvents`! But apparently the closure passed to `empty_data` is not called when the form is submitted and I wonder if `data` supports a closure, especially when I want the inner data to be bound to the user input. Moreover, apparently the form data is still `null` in the `PRE_SUBMIT` event (I think that's what it's supposed to do, but it also means I cannot pass the parent form to the child through the options).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I actually could solve this. It was extremely hack-y, but I have managed to not break proper data encapsulation in this kind of situation. Here, I will explain, and hopefully this will be useful for anyone.

## How to Use Factory Method Pattern in Symfony 2 Forms and Not Die Trying

### Factory Method Pattern

Let's first recap the design pattern. [SourceMaking has a good article on this](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method), but I will write a summary. In short, the Factory Method design pattern allows us to have a method in a parent class that creates an object of another class, with the possibility of being extended and overridden so subclasses can have their own implementation. This is a *creational pattern* and thus deals with creating objects. And as such, Factory Methods allow us to encapsulate the creation of an object for whatever intent.

In my problem, my usage of Factory Method comes from the fact `Child`'s lifecycle depends tightly on `Parent`. This is, no `Parent`, no `Child`, and `Child` cannot live independently from a parent. Thus, `Parent` has a factory method, `createChild`, that will create a `Child` that is immediately bound to it. Furthermore, `Child` has no `setParent` in order to not break proper data encapsulation.

### What is Not Working

In the example, no matter when or how I called `getParent`, I kept getting `null` when I tried to `getData`. That is because there is no data until `SUBMIT`, and at that point I cannot add more form fields. This is also the reason why I couldn't achieve any results at any point.

### The Solution

Let's take a look to `Child`'s constructor method.

```
public function __construct(Parent $parent, $foo, $bar)
{
    $this->parent = $parent;
    $this->foo = $foo;
    $this->bar = $baz;
}
```

As you can see, `__construct` has a tight coupling (anti-pattern, I know, but the business rules are asking me to actually enforce that, so I cannot concede this point) with `Parent`. So, let's give it what it's asking for - we will fix this later.

In `ChildType`:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'My\Bundle\Child',
        'empty_data' => function (FormInterface $form) {
            return new My\Bundle\Child(
                new My\Bundle\Parent(null),
                $form->get('foo')->getData(),
                $form->get('bar')->getData()
            );
        }
    ));
}
```

No, I'm not kidding. I'm basically setting a completely unrelated `Parent` to the `Child` we're constructing. Fear not, we will deal with this shortly.

Symfony forms force me to declare `addChildren` and `removeChildren` in `Parent` when I'm working in a collection. `removeChildren` is easy to implement, but there is a issue: I cannot really `addChildren` **because I cannot set the `Parent` in the `Child`, coupling it with the `Parent` that created it!** So, I worked in a small workaround that does the whole magic!

In `Parent`:

```
public function createChild($foo, $bar)
{
    $child = new Child($this, $foo, $bar);
    $this->getChildren()->add($child);
    return $child;
}

public function addChild(Child $child)
{
    return $this->createChild($child->getFoo(), $child->getBar());
}
```

I couldn't get rid of `getFoo` and `getBar`, but keep in mind those can be neccesary in any other context, and currently I'm letting the object be read-only.

Despite that, what I am doing here is to fabricate a new `Child` based on the specifications `$child` in `addChild` has, much like cloning the whole object. So I am not really adding the incoming `Child` but rather copying its contents to a new fabrication.

### Conclusions

This way I managed to not break data encapsulation, by creating a `Child` in `ChildType` and giving it an unrelated `Parent` and later copying the data when the form invokes `addChild`. That is how I also managed to not break good OO programming and design practices, even with Symfony forms that might look a bit restrictive on that matter.

For a good read about how to use `empty_data` in Symfony, read [William Durand's article on this matter.](http://williamdurand.fr/2013/12/16/enforcing-data-encapsulation-with-symfony-forms/)